# PropertyGrid type object-tree editor for Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some experience with the C# PropertyGrid control, and a love it when you want to easily give the user the ability to directly edit objects in your program. I am looking for something similar in Javascript.

The convenient thing with PropertyGrid is that it detects all the editable properties of an object, and lays itself out accordingly, without you needing to specify all the editable properties. It's also nice that it allows the user to drill down into properties of an object which are objects themselves objects with properties, and can be edited in a tree like manner.

I have seen jqGrid recommended on stackoverflow as a PropertyGrid substitute. It seems like it might be bendable to do what I'm looking for, but I didn't find any example of it being used in this way. It does not appear to have the automatic-layout or tree-like features. Something more akin to the object browser in Chrome's javascript console would be nicer.

Does anybody know of an existing object tree editor of this type? Am I missing some example of jqGrid doing precisely what I want?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI Tree component is [in development](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138128/Tree). Until then, have a look at the [jsTree plugin](http://www.jstree.com/).

<sup>(Site seems to be down right now, [here's the Goog cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://www.jstree.com/))</sup>

Comment: jsTree looks like it might be what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, on closer examination, jsTree still doesn't have the "automatic-layout" behavior I'm looking for. The Tree UI is nice, but looks like I would need to wrap my objects into JSON "nodes" that it likes to display.